Where Is The Implementation for Traverse[IO]
val foo: IO[List[Int]] = List(IO.pure(100)).sequence

Where do I find the implementation for the sequence method? I presume there is a Traverse typeclass implementation for cats.effect.IO and where can I find this implementation? If I am wrong, how does foo above work? Thanks

There no Traverse for IO, well I belive there isn't, and if there is one is not relevant for this example.
There is however a Traverse for List and an Applicative to IO, and since IO also forms a Monad then that one delegate to flatMap.
In general, we know that:
def sequence[A, F[_], G[_]](fga: F[G[A]])(using Traverse[F], Applicative[G]): G[F[A]] =
  traverse(fga)(identity)

trait Traverse[F[_]]:
  def traverse[A, B, G[_]](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[B])(using Applicative[G]): G[F[B]]

And for List the implementation of traverse is as follows:
given Traverse[List] with
  override def traverse[A, B, G[_]](fa: List[A])(f: A => G[B])(Applicative[G]): G[List[B]] =
    fa.foldLeft(Appliative[G].pure(List.empty[B])) {
      case (accG: G[List[B]], a: A) =>
        val gb: G[B] = f(a)
        Appliative[G].map2(accG, gb) {
           case (acc: List[B], b: B) =>
             b :: acc
        }
    }.map(_.reverse) // Or you could use foldRight or another more optimal strategy but that is besides the point.

And we also know that when there is a Monad[G] then:
trait Monad[G[_]] extends Applicative[G]:
  override def map2[A, B, C](ga: G[A], gb: G[B])(f: (A, B) => C): G[C] =
    for
      a <- ga
      b <- gb
      c = f(a, b)
    yield c

So, in other words, this becomes just a traversal of the List using flatMaps.

Relevant sources:

Traverse[List]: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/cats/instances/list.scala#L120
Async[IO]: https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/1ba83f03445ff1cef778c3876486c5bb2b06350a/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IO.scala#L1920
map2 for Monad: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/47fbad764ad8026d4e9f8999c7f6233c666f0df8/core/src/main/scala/cats/FlatMap.scala#L113

The real implementations are, of course, more optimized and a little bit more complex than the ones I used. But conceptually they are equivalent.

Thank you for your elaborated explanation

I'll add to Luis's answer that you can always see how implicits are resolved for example with scalacOptions += "-Vprint:typer"
In scala 2 or 3, is it possible to debug implicit resolution process in runtime?
For
val foo: IO[List[Int]] = List(IO.pure(100)).sequence

this prints
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CD03j1FTSzGK61i5UivDRg
//val foo: cats.effect.IO[List[Int]] = cats.syntax.`package`.traverse.toTraverseOps[List, cats.effect.IO[Int]](scala.`package`.List.apply[cats.effect.IO[Int]](cats.effect.IO.pure[Int](100)))(cats.UnorderedFoldable.catsTraverseForList).sequence[cats.effect.IO, Int](scala.<:<.refl[cats.effect.IO[Int]], cats.effect.IO.asyncForIO);

So it's desugared as
val foo: IO[List[Int]] = cats.syntax.traverse.toTraverseOps[List, cats.effect.IO[Int]](
    scala.List.apply[cats.effect.IO[Int]](cats.effect.IO.pure[Int](100))
  )(cats.UnorderedFoldable.catsTraverseForList)
  .sequence[cats.effect.IO, Int](scala.<:<.refl[cats.effect.IO[Int]], effect.IO.asyncForIO)

So Traverse instance (Traverse[List]) is cats.UnorderedFoldable.catsTraverseForList, and Applicative instance (Applicative[IO]) is cats.effect.IO.asyncForIO.
These instances (Traverse[List], Applicative[IO]) is what you need to transform List[IO[A]] into IO[List[A]]. The instances Traverse[IO], Applicative[List] would be needed if vice versa you wanted to transform IO[List[A]] into List[IO[A]].
See why there is no Traverse[IO] (and Foldable[IO]) instance: Can cats.effect.IO be sequenced, ie is it in the Traverse typeclass?
